# why python3.10 and python3.12 don't import the same modules?

Tags: python-3.x

question. if python3.10 can import modules installed into the same location as  python3.12, then why can't python3.12 import those same modules???

i'm on ubuntu 22.04 using its native python3, i.e., python3.10, and i installed python3.12 via apt with a repository upgrade using `add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`.  i also configured pip to install all packages to the same location using `pip3 config set global.target /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`.

so i pip3'd, say netifaces, using `pip3 install netifaces` and verified it is under the /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ with ls and with `pip list -v`.  so netifaces is definitely there.  i also verified python's paths with:

```
> python3.10 -m site
sys.path = [
    '/root/.config/pip',
    '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

and with:

```
> python3.12 -m site
sys.path = [
    '/root/.config/pip',
    '/usr/lib/python312.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.12',
    '/usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

where you'll see that /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages is in both the python3.10 and in the python3.12 paths.

BUT, when i run:

```
> python3.10 -c "import netifaces"
> python3.12 -c "import netifaces"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netifaces'
```

where obviously 3.10 imports fine BUT 3.12 does not...  why not?  and how do i fix python3.12 importing???

thank you in advance, lucas

Comment: Trying to share installed packages between Python versions is a bad idea. Python was never designed to work like that. You'll get all kinds of weird conflicts.

Comment: oh, crap.  i was hoping to save storage space.  i mean i can understand it between majors, like 2 and 3, but not between minors, especially 10 to only 12.